# Android app won't reopen sites list once closed with back button

Tags: bug, android-app, communities-list

To reproduce:

1. Select **Edit** on *Your Sites*.
2. Tap the dropdown to get the whole list of sites.
3. Tap the phone's back button.

The list disappears and clicking the dropdown does not make it reappear.